# Why can't ACLs block users from having access to their own home directory?

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, acl

CentOS 6.x

In the process of studying ACLs, I came across this blurb in my training documentation:

> However with ACLs, you can't deny access for a user to his home directory

While I can't think of any reason why I would want to do that, I'm curious why administrators are explicitly blocked from even having the possibility of doing this.  Is this something that's hard-coded into `setfacl` or is something else blocking this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing special about a user's home directory that would make permissions different. After all, permissions are handled by the kernel, and the kernel has no concept of home directory.

A user's home directory usually belongs to that user. An ACL for the owner of the file is ignored, the classical permission bits for the owner (set by `chmod u=…`) apply instead. I guess this is what this document is illustrating in a clumsy way.

If you make a user's home directory not executable by that user, then they will be left in the root directory when they log in.